# How to read and write a vector of struct to a file?

Tags: c++, file, vector, struct, fstream

I am currently trying to read and write a vector of structs to a binary file, such that I don't spends on preprocessing it with filling it up all the time.

I seem to have some problems doing so... I though that i could `std::ofstream` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

struct element
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> coord;
    element(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> set_coord )
    {
         coord = set_coord;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
    std::vector<element> matrix;

    std::ofstream datafile;
    datafile.open("path/to/file");
    datafile<<matrix;
    datafile.close();
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/urCHoETdh7vE3xlE

I am getting an error message that the `operator<<` is not valid here... but why?

Comment: At a push, I'd say it's because you've not implemented it.   what you want to look up is operator overloading

Comment: Because it's not valid. The actual message, not a paraphrase, is `prog.cc:25:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream' {aka 'std::basic_ofstream<char>'} and 'std::vector<element>')`, and that's perfectly correct and clear; there is no `operator<<` defined for those types of operands. I mean, you thought that you could just feed anything to an `ofstream`, and it would somehow innately know how to format it for output, and in whatever specific way that you want?

Comment: I made a minor change, from two ints to a vector of pairs... It no way possible to store it without having to define a routine that dissects the data structure to its core (ints) and store int's individually?

Comment: What would this imagined default output format be like? Comma-separated? Tab-separated? JSON? There's no way for the stdlib to pick a good default that everyone will like - nor, more basically, to know which members the user will or will not want to output - so users have to define their own methods of formatting data for output.

Comment: It is always good practice to make sure that you did indeed open the file with `is_open`, and if you want a binary file it may also be a good idea to specify ios::out | ios::bin.   Once you do that, since you want to store this in binary you need to think of how to store it in binary, and since you are using a vector, how are you going to tell it how many elements are stored?

Comment: You should do some research on serialization. For a simple binary file you'll want to write the number of elements stored in the file. You can't use the size and divide since they are variable. For each element you will want to write the number of coordinates and then each pair. To read it back you do the opposite. For a robust implementation you may want to version your data in case you need to change the format later and want to be able to read older files and convert them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the stream operator directly you have to overload it for your struct. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct {
    using coordinates = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;
    MyStruct(coordinates c) : c(c) {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStruct& m) {
        for (const auto &pair : m.c) {
            os << "First: " << pair.first << "; Second: " << pair.second;
        }
        return os;
    }

private:
    coordinates c;
};

class MyVector {
public:
    MyVector(std::initializer_list<MyStruct> list) : elements(list) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyVector& m) {
        for (const auto &ms : m.elements) {
            os << ms << std::endl;
        }
        return os;
    }

private:
    std::vector<MyStruct> elements;
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct m1({{1, 2}});
    MyStruct m2({{3, 4}});
    MyVector vec({m1, m2});
    std::cout << vec << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've edited the code so it does work with a vector as a member. And in a second edit I am using my own (very basic) vector implementation

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s9JtGkifi3cpxjdP) is the code on wandbox

Comment: Not just struct; but vector too.

Comment: @UKMonkey Just now realized he wants to output a whole vector. I changed my code so this is possible in a very basic manner.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which clearly states `binary file`.